# Nested dialog issue with Primefaces 4 Dialog Framework?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

How to do for nested dialog using `Primefaces 4's Dialog Framework`?

Process is

```
register.xml        --->    selectCityDialog.xtml   --->    selectProvinceDialog.xhtml
RegisterBean.java   --->    CityDialogBean.java     --->    ProvinceDialogBean.java
```

When Primefaces show `selectProvinceDialog`,

- UI appearance is not like before `Primefaces 3.x` (Incorrect UI)
- All of `commandbutton/link` does not work.
- `CityDialogBean` cannot get return value from `ProvinceDialogBean`.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use "PF 4 Dialog Framework" but be careful, it does not work in the same way that the common `<p:dialog />` component.

It is easier in my opinion to use the `<p:dialog />` component if you want everything you've done before, works well.

Adding `<p:dialog />` will create a HTML `<div />` in the same view (same context)

But Adding a dialog with the "dialog Framework" will create a HTML `<iframe />`, which is not in the same view (different context), that's the reason why all your links do not work well.

If you still want to use the dialog framework, you have to be familiar with the `dialogReturn` ajax event

I think this will help you : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dialogFrameworkData.jsf
or downlaod the documentation here : http://www.primefaces.org/documentation

Answer (score 0):

example here dialog framework with crud: 
http://deividnn.net/2014/04/07/como-usar-o-dialog-framework-data-do-primefaces-4/

Code: https://github.com/deividnn/jsf-primefaces/tree/master/jsfPrimefaces-dialogFramework